# I can't get this program to output the final calculation to the webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the value of the calculation to output to the screen on the webpage after the user has hit the "Convert" button. I have checked the console multiple times while submitting the form, but to no avail, there isn't a single error.

I also know that the entire code is being interpreted because I placed an alert at the bottom of the JS body and it showed up when I loaded the page.

Also am quite new to programming with only a few weeks experience, so I appreciate if I have made any tiny silly mistakes. Thanks

Code:

```js
function setup() {
 
 document.getElementById("currencyValue").style.background = "white";
 document.getElementById("currencyValue").value = "";
 document.getElementById("currency1").value = "GBP";
 document.getElementById("currency2").value = "GBP";
 
}

function validate() {
 
 var valid = true;
 var currencyValue = document.getElementById("currencyValue").value;
 
 if (isNaN(currencyValue) == true) {
  document.getElementById("currencyValue").style.background = "crimson";
  alert("Please enter a numeric value");
  valid = false;
 } else if (currencyValue == "") {
  document.getElementById("currencyValue").style.background = "crimson";
  alert("Please enter a value");
  valid = false;
 } else {
  document.getElementById("currencyValue").style.background = "white";
 }
}

if (valid = true) {
 function calculate() {

  var finalCalc;
  var currencySymbol;
  var currencyCalc1 = document.getElementById("currency1").value;
  var currencyCalc2 = document.getElementById("currency2").value;

  //[gbp], [eur], [jpy], [usd]
  const gbp = [1, 1.12, 131.86, 1.23];
  const eur = [0.89, 1, 117.43, 1.10];
  const jpy = [0.0076, 0.0085, 1, 0.0094];
  const usd = [0.81, 0.91, 106.94, 1];

  if (currencyCalc1 == "GBP" && currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
   finalCalc = gbp[0];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "GBP" && currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
   finalCalc = gbp[1];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "GBP" && currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
   finalCalc = gbp[2];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "GBP" && currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
   finalCalc = gbp[3];
  //EUR
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "EUR" && currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
   finalCalc = eur[0];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "EUR" && currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
   finalCalc = eur[1];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "EUR" && currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
   finalCalc = eur[2];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "EUR" && currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
   finalCalc = eur[3];
  //JPY
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "JPY" && currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
   finalCalc = jpy[0];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "JPY" && currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
   finalCalc = jpy[1];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "JPY" && currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
   finalCalc = jpy[2];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "JPY" && currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
   finalCalc = jpy[3];
  //USD
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "USD" && currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
   finalCalc = usd[0];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "USD" && currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
   finalCalc = usd[1];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "USD" && currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
   finalCalc = usd[2];
  } else if (currencyCalc1 == "USD" && currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
   finalCalc = usd[3];
  }
   

  if (currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
   currencySymbol = "£";
  } else if (currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
   currencySymbol = "€";
  } else if (currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
   currencySymbol = "¥";
  } else if (currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
   currencySymbol = "$";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("finalResult").innerHTML = currencySymbol + (finalCalc * currencyValue);
  
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Currency converter</title>
    <link href="currencyStyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon"></link>
    <script src="currencyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="containerDiv">
        <h3 id="title">CURRENCY CONVERTER</h3>
        <div class="userInterfaceDivs">
            <table id="userInterfaceTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Convert  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="currencyValue" class="interfaceElements" type="text" placeholder="Currency">
                        <select id="currency1" class="interfaceElements">
                        <option>GBP</option>
                        <option>EUR</option>
                        <option>JPY</option>
                        <option>USD</option>
                    </td>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td>
                        to  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="currency2" class="interfaceElements">
                        <option>GBP</option>
                        <option>EUR</option>
                        <option>JPY</option>
                        <option>USD</option>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="interfaceElements" type="button" onClick="validate()">Convert</button>
                        <button class="interfaceElements" type="button" onClick="setup()">Reset</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="userInterfaceDivs" id="resultDiv">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>The result is: </td>
                    <td id="finalResult"> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `calculate()` called? I don't see that in your HTML...

Comment: Also, variable `currencyValue` is not instantiated anywhere

Comment: what is ur validate function () ? i can not find it in ur code

Comment: Not related to your problem, but this code can be shortened a lot: https://jsbin.com/qadoforuxi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Putting an alert at the end of the JS body means that the body has been parsed, and the top level executed, however your function may only have been declared but not run.

Comment: Try putting an alert at the end of the calculate function, just after the line which writes to the finalResult innerHTML and see if that gets hit - my bet is it does not.

Comment: sorry i trimmed the JS and HTML a bit...shouldn't have done that to avoid confusion. I'll edit the html and JS body to show the full code

Comment: Show the `validate` Function.

Comment: @EuanSmith you were right, no alert displays when i insert one at the end of calculate(). I'm not sure what the mistake i made there

Comment: @Cerbrus thank you, I will bear that in mind next time I make a program, however for the benefit of my lack of understanding since i'm new, i'm just going to stick with my long and inefficient code because i understand it better. p.s. i told my friends that i knew that there was a much shorter way to do it, but i couldn't find or understand how.

Comment: No problem. Now, your problem is that you're not calling `calculate()` anywhere. You probably want to do that at the end of your `validate` function, if all validation is passed successfully.

Comment: The key comment is the first one from @Cerbrus - you are not actually calling calculate anywhere.

Comment: damn i knew it was something tiny. Thank you, however i tried to make a variable ("valid") check whether any inputted values were false, and then deciding whether calculate() would be executed based on the Boolean value of the variable "valid", but it doesn't seem to work. i will update the original post to show the new code

Comment: Your `if` condition is now completely outside of thew `validate` function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 problems in the code.

1. You are not calling the `calculate` function at all.
   call the `calculate` function inside the `validate` function's else section
2. The `currencyValue` variable is not initiating inside the `calculate` function.
   Initiate at the start of `calculate` function

I just added the comment on changes in the below code please review.

```
    function setup() {

      document.getElementById("currencyValue").style.background = "white";
      document.getElementById("currencyValue").value = "";
      document.getElementById("currency1").value = "GBP";
      document.getElementById("currency2").value = "GBP";

    }

    function validate() {

      var currencyValue = document.getElementById("currencyValue").value;

      if (isNaN(currencyValue) == true) {
        document.getElementById("currencyValue").style.background = "crimson";
        alert("Please enter a numeric value");
      } else if (currencyValue == "") {
        document.getElementById("currencyValue").style.background = "crimson";
        alert("Please enter a value");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("currencyValue").style.background = "white";
        calculate();// here is calling the calculate function after validating the input.
      }

    }


    function calculate() {

      var finalCalc;
      var currencySymbol;
      var currencyCalc1 = document.getElementById("currency1").value;
      var currencyCalc2 = document.getElementById("currency2").value;
      //currencyValue initiating from input field.
      var currencyValue = document.getElementById("currencyValue").value;

      //[gbp], [eur], [jpy], [usd]
      const gbp = [1, 1.12, 131.86, 1.23];
      const eur = [0.89, 1, 117.43, 1.10];
      const jpy = [0.0076, 0.0085, 1, 0.0094];
      const usd = [0.81, 0.91, 106.94, 1];

      if (currencyCalc1 == "GBP" && currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
        finalCalc = gbp[0];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "GBP" && currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
        finalCalc = gbp[1];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "GBP" && currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
        finalCalc = gbp[2];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "GBP" && currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
        finalCalc = gbp[3];
        //EUR
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "EUR" && currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
        finalCalc = eur[0];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "EUR" && currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
        finalCalc = eur[1];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "EUR" && currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
        finalCalc = eur[2];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "EUR" && currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
        finalCalc = eur[3];
        //JPY
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "JPY" && currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
        finalCalc = jpy[0];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "JPY" && currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
        finalCalc = jpy[1];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "JPY" && currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
        finalCalc = jpy[2];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "JPY" && currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
        finalCalc = jpy[3];
        //USD
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "USD" && currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
        finalCalc = usd[0];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "USD" && currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
        finalCalc = usd[1];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "USD" && currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
        finalCalc = usd[2];
      } else if (currencyCalc1 == "USD" && currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
        finalCalc = usd[3];
      }


      if (currencyCalc2 == "GBP") {
        currencySymbol = "£";
      } else if (currencyCalc2 == "EUR") {
        currencySymbol = "€";
      } else if (currencyCalc2 == "JPY") {
        currencySymbol = "¥";
      } else if (currencyCalc2 == "USD") {
        currencySymbol = "$";
      }

      document.getElementById("finalResult").innerHTML = currencySymbol + (finalCalc * currencyValue);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the reason I am initializing the currencyValue variable within the validate() function is to check if a numeric value has been inputted, although i did try to initialize it in the calculate() function at the start but it didn't work. Also, i tried calling calculate() in the else section of validate(), and I am getting results now, however they look like this now: The result is:   â‚¬NaN (displays when converting 1GBP to EUR)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t92pq01L/3/  please review this one. that link is not saved that's why not working

Comment: thank you! it works now, however a weird accented leter keeps showing up in front? random letter each time. i.e. £55 > GBP = "Â£551"

Comment: No, I try but I didn't get the extra character 55 EUR to GBP The result is: £48.95